# Prepared statements: num_rows is always zero

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

I am in the process of converting my site to prepared statements (before I just relied on a custom function that included mysqli_real_escape_string, among others), but when I run the code, I always get zero records. I know the SQL is fine because I can run the SQL in the MySQL workbench tool and it returns several records. Here is my code:

```
<?php
$link = new mysqli($server,$dbusername,$dbpassword,$database);
if($link->connect_error){
    die($link->connect_error);
}

$sql = "select itemname from items where itemcategory = ?";
//if(!$query = mysqli_query($link, $sql)) die(mysqli_error($link));
if(!$stmt = $link->prepare($sql)) die("Error");

$stmt->bind_param("i", $category); //replace question mark with category id
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($itemname);
//$numitems = mysqli_num_rows($query);
$numitems = $stmt->num_rows;

if($numitems>0){
    //while($array = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
    while($stmt->fetch()) {
        echo $itemname."<br>";
    }
}
$stmt->close();
?>
```

`$stmt->num_rows` is always 0. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is actually documented in the php doc for `mysqli_stmt_num_rows`

> Returns the number of rows in the result set. The use of mysqli_stmt_num_rows() depends on whether or not you used mysqli_stmt_store_result() to buffer the entire result set in the statement handle.

So because the result has been not transferred to statement handle, you cannot calculate the rows properly. Thats why the solution is like you mentioned:

```
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$stmt->bind_result($itemname);
$numitems = $stmt->num_rows;
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem was solved by changing

```
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($itemname);
```

to

```
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$stmt->bind_result($itemname);
```